# How to color a perfect reflective material in cycles?

Tags: rendering, shaders

This is maybe a funny question, but when I color a reflective material, I just change the color of the "glossy" shader, but when it comes to darker colors, I'm lost, because the gradient from dark to light changes the reflection amount too. In the real world full reflections have no colors, but is it possible to color a perfect reflective material in blender regardless of the color surroundings (non realistic soloring)?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to color it using the Color input for the Glossy shader; Is that the case? If so, that only changes the color that is reflected; to color the surface, you use a Diffuse shader and a Mix node.

Comment: Thanks. Basically to color a perfect reflective material. The approach doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.. Could you explain what exactly the color input of the glossy node isn't doing?

Comment: @someonewithpc In reality you never see the surface of the object, you only see light reflected off the surface. This goes for diffuse just as much as glossy objects. A glossy object and a diffuse object are the same, the only difference is the way the light is reflected; diffuse scatters reflected light in all directions, glossy does not.

Comment: @gandalf3 That much I know... But in glossy surfaces, if the color is set to black, it wont reflect any light; The reason is that value controls the color of glossy rays, i.e. reflected light.

Comment: Thanks gandalf3. I know that. That's why I love cycles, because it is physically accurate, however I want the non realistic way of shading. I want full reflection, together with a color and at the same time to be able to change the tone of the color from dark to light. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

[image]

This way the camera will see the object with the dark color, but other objects will "see" the object with a bright color, reflecting more light:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My knowledge is a little limited on cycles, but that's pretty close to what I want. Basically, the effect that I want to achieve is when you combine a diffuse shader - for the color; and a glossy shader; for the reflection;. That is the coloring effect that I want to achieve on a final render, however the reflections to look as if only a glossy shader is used at full amount (non realistic). I like your example, but if you come up with something better, will be awesome, 'cause the color looks very transparent or I have to study physics some more. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you want, but I added in some diffuse.

Comment: Just to ask, how do you have the "Light part" node with only "In camera ray" displayed? Is it the same "Input"/"Light path"?

Comment: @Vladimir Yes. I just hid the extra sockets with Ctrl+H

Comment: Ok, 'cause when I hide a node on the arrow, it is pointing on right, but yours is still pointing down, that was strange to me. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Vladimir Hiding (Ctrl+H) and collapsing (H) are different operations.

Comment: Man, I have to take some time with the node editor. Thanks.